# wsgen exposes methods that are not annotated with @WebMethod

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, webmethod

I have the following minimal webservice defined:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class DummyWS {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String url= "http://localhost:8888/Dummy";
    final Endpoint endpoint= Endpoint.create(new DummyWS());
    endpoint.publish(url);
  }

  @WebMethod
  public void putData(final String value) {
    System.out.println("value: "+value);
  }

  @WebMethod
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("doing nothing");
  }


  public void myInternalMethod() {
    System.out.println("should not be exposed via WSDL");
  }
}
```

As you can see I have two methods I want to expose, since they are annotated with `@WebMethod`: `putData` and `doSomething`. 
But when running wsgen, it generates a WSDL that contains the `myInternalMethod` although it is *not* annotated.

Do I have a misconfiguration here? Why is a method exposed that is not annotated with @WebMethod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it. Per default *all* public methods are exposed. To exclude a method one must annotate it with `@WebMethod(exclude=true)`.
This is quite a strange requirement, because it means that I only have to annotate those methods with `@WebMethod` that I do *not* want to expose.

This is the correct code then:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class DummyWS {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String url= "http://localhost:8888/Dummy";
    final Endpoint endpoint= Endpoint.create(new DummyWS());
    endpoint.publish(url);
  }

  public void putData(final String value) {
    System.out.println("value: "+value);
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("doing nothing");
  }


  @WebMethod(exclude=true)
  public void myInternalMethod() {
    System.out.println("should not be exposed via WSDL");
  }
}
```